# Determinate if a column contain numeric value in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have to determinate if a column contains a numeric or a alphanumeri value.

My sql code is:
*select
case when trim(TRANSLATE(my_column, '0123456789-,.', ' ')) is null
then 'integer'
else 'char'
end
from my_table*

and i have to traslate it in JPQL.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you need to check this column for numeric, alphanumeric, or both?

Comment: i need to extract only those records with alphanumeric values

Comment: What is your database (e.g. MySQL, Oracle), and are you open to using a native query?

Comment: database is ORACLE, i have to use jpql and not native queries

Comment: You can't really do this from JPQL (not easily, at least).  I suggest using a native Oracle query.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to rewrite the whole query just to determine if a field is numeric or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is easy to come by using a native Oracle query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(my_column, '[A-Za-z0-9]');
```

The above will match any record having at least one alphanumeric character in the `my_column` column.  You *can't* do this from JPQL directly.  The best you might be able to do is to use a large number of `LIKE` statements, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_column LIKE '%A%' OR
      my_column LIKE '%B%' OR
      ...
```

for every alphanumeric value.  But this is unwieldy, and probably should be avoided.  There is nothing wrong with using a native query if the situation merits that one should be used.

Comment: ok, i will use a native query, thanks